# Mysql query browser not showing schemata (databases)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-workbench

[image: Mysql query browser not showing schemata (databases)]

Hello, people, I'd appreciate it if you could assist me with this problem. I'm using workbench and mysql, and I have a few schemata (databases) in my sql. However, when I log in using Mysql Query Browser, it doesn't show my schemata (databases), but it does when I use workbench.

Comment: Sound like different users are connecting. This means the user with less access sees fewer schemas.

Comment: Check the "user" being connected from each tool.

Comment: With which user are you connecting in MySQL Server Workbench? And in MySQL Query Browser? Are you connecting to the same host/server? Do you have multiple MySQL instances running on different ports? Please [edit] your question and add as much details as possible without providing your actual users/passwords.